# Android Square Picasso not load Turkish character image url

Tags: android, picasso

I try use square picasso a web Application.
But if my img url contains Turkish characters.
Picasso not load img.

This URL is working.
http://www.bulenttiras.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/kokhucre.jpg

but

This URL not working
http://www.bulenttiras.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/t%C3%BCp-bebek-tedavisi.jpg

```
public class CategoryAdapterClass extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<CategoryHelper> categoryHelpers;
        private Context context;

        public CategoryAdapterClass(List<CategoryHelper> categoryHelpers, Context context) {
            this.categoryHelpers = categoryHelpers;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return categoryHelpers.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CategoryHelper getItem(int position) {
            return categoryHelpers.get( position );
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            CategoryHelper categoryHelper   = getItem( position );

            if( convertView == null ) {

                viewHolder                  = new ViewHolder();
                convertView                 = LayoutInflater.from( context ).inflate(R.layout.all_categories_inflate, parent, false);

                viewHolder.categoryImage    = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.categoryImage );
                viewHolder.category_title   = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.category_title );
                viewHolder.category_excerpt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.category_excerpt );

                convertView.setTag( viewHolder );
            }
            else {
                viewHolder          = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            String query = null;
            try {
                query = URLEncoder.encode(categoryHelper.getCategory_image(), "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            viewHolder.category_title.setText( categoryHelper.getCategory_image() );
            viewHolder.category_excerpt.setText( categoryHelper.getCategory_excerpt() );
            Picasso.with( context ).load( query ).into( viewHolder.categoryImage );

            return convertView;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            ImageView categoryImage;
            TextView category_title;
            TextView category_excerpt;
        }
    }
```

Please help.
Sorry bad english.
Thank you.

Comment: May be you should use URL Encoder

Comment: I try this " String urlencode = Uri.encode( "imageurl" ) " 
But not fixed

Comment: You should upload your code in question.

Comment: http://www.bulenttiras.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/t%C3%BCp-bebek-tedavisi.jpg is already encoded. You don't need to encode it again.

Comment: @Barışcan Kayaoğlu what can I do ? Can you help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627568/android-square-picasso-not-load-persian-character-image-url

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The only option i could find was replacing all the single Turkish character with the encoded one.

```
public static String encodeTurkishCharactersInUrl(String url) {
        String[] list = new String[] {"ü","ç","ı","ö","ğ","ş"," ","Ü","Ç","İ","Ö","Ğ","Ş"};
        for (int i = 0; i< list.length ; i++) {
            try {
                url = url.replace(list[i], URLEncoder.encode(list[i],"UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return url;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably missing internet permission on your manifest.

Edit: Here's the code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>




public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://www.bulenttiras.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/t%C3%BCp-bebek-tedavisi.jpg").into((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1), new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.v("Information", "Success!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.v("Information", "FAIL!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No not missing İnternet Permisson. This URL : http://www.bulenttiras.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/kokhucre.jpg is working

Comment: Add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> at your AndroidManifest.xml outside of application tag.

Comment: Hmm.. I just tried your url, http://www.bulenttiras.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/t%C3%BCp-bebek-tedavisi.jpg and i can see the picture.

Comment: Yes web browsers show picture. But android picasso not showing.

Comment: I edited the answer with an example code, check it out.

Comment: İngilizcem yetmedi böyle soracağım mecburen. Senin yaptığın örneği çalıştırdığımda sorunsuz geliyor resimler. Sorunu buldum bunu görünce de. Benim JSON dan aldığım veri "http://www.bulenttiras.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/tüp-bebek-tedavisi.jpg" şeklinde geliyor. Yani içinde türkçe karakter barındırarak. yani tüp-bebek yazan yerde t%C3%BCp-bebek yazmıyor. Dümdüz geliyor. Sorunumu anlatabildim umarım.