# Android Square Picasso not load persian character image url

Tags: android, picasso

I want to create web application by square picasso, but if image url contains persian characters (ا،ب،ج،ی، ...) Picasso not load image.

This url not working:

```
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://www.shutterstock.ir/thumbs/10006/74601661-گربه-چشم-ابی-ولاغر-سیامی-در-یک-پس-زمینه-،-وکتور-سفید.jpg")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .error(R.drawable.face_top_image).noFade().resize(100, 100)
    .into(imageView);
```

This url work

```
        Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://www.shutterstock.ir/thumbs/10006/74601661-%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%87-%DA%86%D8%B4%D9%85-%D8%A7%D8%A8%DB%8C-%D9%88%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%BA%D8%B1-%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D9%BE%D8%B3-%D8%B2%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%8C-%D9%88%DA%A9%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%B1-%D8%B3%D9%81%DB%8C%D8%AF.jpg")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .error(R.drawable.face_top_image).noFade().resize(100, 100)
    .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to URI encode the URL.

See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode(java.lang.String))

```
Uri.encode(url);
```

Or, if specifying certain allowed characters the following works:

```
private static final String ALLOWED_URI_CHARS = "@#&=*+-_.,:!?()/~'%";
String urlEncoded = Uri.encode(path, ALLOWED_URI_CHARS);
```

Comment: `Uri.encode(url)` will encode the whole string, including `://` and forward-slash in path.  The best way is to use `ALLOWED_URI_CHARS` which escape those `:` and `/`s.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your `Url` .
So try this

```
URIUtil.encodeQuery(myUrl).
```

or also this one : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html

```
URLEncoder.encode(myUrl, "UTF-8");
```

Also there is an issue [here](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/652)

Comment: Seems `URIUtil` has been removed or relocated somewhere else in 4.5.4.  I had a hard time to resolve which package of apache to include.

Answer (score 0):

> just use from this function

```
 public static String encodUrl(String url){
            String[] splitUrl = url.split("/");
            String imageName = splitUrl[splitUrl.length-1];//get name of file
            String mainUrl = url.replaceAll(imageName , "");//get url without file name bacause dont need to encode

            return (mainUrl + Uri.encode(imageName));
        }
```