# Picasso not loading url with Turkish characters

Tags: android, picasso, imageurl, turkish

I am using Picasso image loading library and found its not loading some urls contains Turkish characters

for example following url making problem    [https://satis.ugur.com.tr/uploads/user_1122/images/ued%20buzdolabı%20görseli.png](https://satis.ugur.com.tr/uploads/user_1122/images/ued%20buzdolab%C4%B1%20g%C3%B6rseli.png)

tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931499/932219) but not working

```
public static String encodeTurkishCharactersInUrl(String url) {
        String[] list = new String[] {"ü","ç","ı","ö","ğ","ş"," ","Ü","Ç","İ","Ö","Ğ","Ş"};
        for (int i = 0; i< list.length ; i++) {
            try {
                url = url.replace(list[i], URLEncoder.encode(list[i],"UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by avoiding empty space with UTF8 encoding and manually replacing all spaces with %20, Now urls are working

```
public static String encodeTurkishCharactersInUrl(String url) {
        String[] list = new String[]{"ü", "ç", "ı", "ö", "ğ", "ş", "", "Ü", "Ç", "İ", "Ö", "Ğ", "Ş"};
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            try {
                url = url.replace(list[i], URLEncoder.encode(list[i], "UTF-8"));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        url = url.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

        return url;
    }
```